# Core Location not working in Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I am developing an application in Xcode 7.3 for iphone 9.3.3 in Objective-C. I followed the suggestions found on this site -- http://nevan.net/2014/09/core-location-manager-changes-in-ios-8/ to get the iphone's location. I am testing what I have so far using an iphone 9.3.3 over lightning cable.

I have "NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription" added to the plist with a value of "Request Location".

I am confused as to why this isn't working. I am not getting any strings with the location over NSLog.

Any help is highly appreciated.

---

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>


@interface ViewController : UIViewController<CLLocationManagerDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@property (weak, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locations;


//

//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *longitudelabel;

//@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *latitudelabel;


@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

#import "ViewController.h"





@interface ViewController ()

{

    NSUserDefaults *defaults;

}



@end



@implementation PollenViewController



- (void)viewDidLoad

{

    [super viewDidLoad];



     // ** Don't forget to add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in MyApp-Info.plist and give it a string



     self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

     self.locationManager.delegate = self;

    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

     // Check for iOS 8. Without this guard the code will crash with "unknown selector" on iOS 7.

     if ([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestWhenInUseAuthorization)]) {

         [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];

     }

     [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];



}


-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated

{

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


}


// Location Manager Delegate Methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations

{

    NSLog(@"%@", [locations lastObject]);

}

@end
```

Comment: what is wrong with ur code ? is locations nil ?

Comment: You're going to need to debug your code. Check the value of authorizationStatus before and after calling requestWhenInUseAuthorization. Also implement the delegate method `locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:` to see the authorization status change.

Comment: @DuncanC I changed my .m to the following -- [link](http://i.imgur.com/m3quLKk.png), and stepped through it with the debugger. When [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization]; is called nothing happens in the app. I also tried [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization] and got nothing. Any hints on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

With iOS 8, requesting permission and beginning to use location services are now separate actions. Since

```
requestWhenInUseAuthorization
```

and

```
requestAlwaysAuthorization
```

methods runs asynchronously, the app can't start the location services immediately. Instead, you need to implement

```
 locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus
```

delegate method as follows, which fires any time the authorization status changes based on user input.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {

  if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways 
       || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
       [manager startUpdatingLocation];
  }
}
```

If the user has previously given permission to use location services, the delegate method will also be called after the location manager is initialized and has its delegate set with the appropriate authorization status as follows

```
CLLocationManager *manager = [CLLocationManager new]
Manager.delegate = self;
if [CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled] {
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to get the location and display it in the app with the following code for ViewController.m. @DuncanC's comment helped alot. This also includes the reverse geocoding.

-Used NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription in the Info.plists with String "Need Location".
-Made sure Settings->Privacy->Location Services->AppName was set to "While Using" not "Never".

Hope this is helpful to anyone who's stuck.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h"

@interface ViewController ()
{
    NSUserDefaults *defaults;

    NSString *locationfound;


}

@property (strong, nonatomic) CLLocationManager *locationManager;

@end

@implementation PollenViewController {
    CLGeocoder *geocoder;
    CLPlacemark *placemark;
    }


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //implement location finder
    self.locationManager=[[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    self.locationManager.delegate=self;
    self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

    //initialize geocoder for later
   geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];


}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];


}
//CURRENTLY WORKING LOCATION MANAGER
//roughly based on ---/*https://gist.github.com/paulw11/84b18044942e2ceea52a8*/

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didChangeAuthorizationStatus:
(CLAuthorizationStatus)status {
    defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    NSLog(@"Callback");
    NSLog(@"status %i",status);
    if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedAlways || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusAuthorizedWhenInUse) {
        NSLog(@"Authorized");
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    } else if (status == kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied || status == kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted) {
        NSLog(@"Denied");
        locationfound=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Location Found"];;
        self.LocationLabel.text=locationfound;

    }else{
        [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
        [self.locationManager  requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    }
}

// Location Manager Delegate Methods
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    CLLocation *newLocation = [locations lastObject];

    NSLog(@"Location new %@",newLocation) ;

    // Reverse Geocoding
    NSLog(@"Resolving the Address");
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:newLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
        defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

//        NSLog(@"Found placemarks: %@, error: %@", placemarks, error);

        if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {
            placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
            locationfound= [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@, %@",
                                placemark.locality,
                                 placemark.administrativeArea];
            NSLog(@"%@",locationfound);
            self.LocationLabel.text=locationfound;
        } else {
            NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);
            locationfound=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"No Location Found"];;
            self.LocationLabel.text=locationfound;
        }

    } ];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager*) manager didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
```

To see if the update is failing and why